# Open and bounded set with compact boundary

Tags: general-topology

Why does an open and bounded set in an infinite dimensional space have to be the emty set, if it has a compact boundary? And the space has a norm, by the way.

Cheers,
Richard

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an open and bounded set whose bonduary $\mbox{bd} A$ is an compact set. It is easy to observe that $$A\subset\overline{\mbox{conv}}(\mbox{bd} A) =B$$ but then by Mazur theorem the set $B$ is compact. So we obtain an compact set $B$ with nonempty interior in infinite dimensional Banach space which is obviously impossible.

Comment: Can you also include the reference of Mazur theorem? Thanks. Also, does $\overline{conv}$ means the convex hull?

Comment: Theorem 4.2.11 here: http://books.google.pl/books?id=6AjuCoaL34AC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=convex+envelope+mazurs+theorem&source=bl&ots=8fLE1UKtuX&sig=LYJr6aPjmh6RjMamMDdw0FmX67s&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=hhhfVITmB9bfasOYgMAL&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: The link doesn't work..